# Why the nodejs program exit when using await & EventEmitter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

Look at this code:

```
const { EventEmitter } = require('events');

class Trigger extends EventEmitter {
  constructor () {
    super();
  }

  run() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.emit('done');
    }, 1000);
  }

  waitUntilDone() {
    const this_ = this;
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this_.on('done', () => {
        resolve();
      });
    })
  }
}

async function main() {
  const tr = new Trigger();
  tr.run();
  console.log('run');
  // 如果监听的事件永远不会抛出，则此处程序会直接退出
  await tr.waitUntilDone().then(() => console.log('Promise done'));
  await tr.waitUntilDone().then(() => console.log('Promise done'));
  console.log('final done');
}

main();
```

The program will exit at the second `await tr.waitUntilDone().t...`, with nothing logged.

Even the second `tr.waitUntilDone()` can never got the event, it should wait forever, isn't it?

Comment: Keep in mind that node.js does not wait for promises to resolve before exiting.  It does wait for timers (unless you `.unref()` them).  And, remember that `main()` returns a promise immediately.  It isn't blocked by `await`.

Comment: @Sashi it exits early. Pingze, `const this_ = this;` is unnecessary since you're using arrow functions.

Comment: So, I suppose it's possible that node.js exits between the time the second timer fires and before your second `.then()` handler gets called, thus skipping the `final done` logging.

Answer (score 0):

If you reset your timer after the first promise resolves the program will not exit until the last promise resolves.

```
async function main() {
    const tr = new Trigger();
    tr.run();
    console.log('run');

    await tr.waitUntilDone().then(() => { 
        console.log('Promise done'); 
        // Reset the timer (this will keep the program alive)
        tr.run();
    });
    await tr.waitUntilDone().then(() => console.log('Promise done'));
    console.log('final done');
}
```

You'll see the output:

```
run
Promise done
Promise done
final done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you must using only 1 thing: Promise or Async/Await.

1] Async/Await example

```
async function main() {
    const tr = new Trigger();
    console.log('run');

    tr.run();
    await tr.waitUntilDone();
    console.log('Promise done');

    tr.run();
    await tr.waitUntilDone();
    console.log('Promise done')

    console.log('final done');
}
```

2] Promise example

```
function main() {
  const tr = new Trigger();
  console.log('run');
  tr.run();
  tr.waitUntilDone().then(() => console.log('Promise done'));
  tr.waitUntilDone().then(() => console.log('Promise done'));
  console.log('final done');
}
```

Your expression "`await tr.waitUntilDone().then(() => console.log('Promise done'));`" is not correct. Correct will be something like this "`await tr.waitUntilDone().then(() => (console.log('Promise done'), Promise.resolve()));`" or "`tr.waitUntilDone().then(() => console.log('Promise done'));`"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your program alive forever, you could add this to the top of your code:

```
(function keepalive() {
    setTimeout(keepalive, 0x7FFFFFFF);
})();
```

Basically, as long as there is a pending event, the runtime should stay open.  Hope this is helpful.